# Pcolormesh not getting correct position matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting data on top of a png image with this code:

```
x, y = np.genfromtxt('pogba_t1314.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)

print(x[1], y[1])
y = y[np.logical_not(np.isnan(y))]
x = x[np.logical_not(np.isnan(x))]
k = gaussian_kde(np.vstack([x, y]))
xi, yi = np.mgrid[x.min():x.max():x.size**0.5*1j,y.min():y.max():y.size**0.5*1j]
zi = k(np.vstack([xi.flatten(), yi.flatten()]))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)

ax1.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi.reshape(xi.shape), alpha=0.5)

ax1.plot(y,x, "o")
ax1.set_xlim(0, 740)
ax1.set_ylim(515, 0)

im = plt.imread('statszone_football_pitch.png')
ax1.imshow(im, extent=[0, 740, 0, 515], aspect='auto')
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Pcolormesh should be over the whole image, but it is not. How can i set the correct position?
Why i get smaller pcolormesh respect of whole pitch? I should have something like this (even if this refers to contourf):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine. The problem is that what represents your x-axis in the image is not what you giving as x-axis in the plot. That said if you change x to y (and vice-versa) you'll obtain the correct plot:

```
from scipy.stats.kde import gaussian_kde
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.genfromtxt('pogba_t1314.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)

print(x[1], y[1])
y = y[np.logical_not(np.isnan(y))]
x = x[np.logical_not(np.isnan(x))]
k = gaussian_kde(np.vstack([x, y]))
#xi, yi = np.mgrid[x.min():x.max():x.size**0.5*1j,y.min():y.max():y.size**0.5*1j]
xi, yi = np.mgrid[y.min():y.max():y.size**0.5*1j,x.min():x.max():x.size**0.5*1j] # Changed this.
#zi = k(np.vstack([xi.flatten(), yi.flatten()]))
zi = k(np.vstack([yi.flatten(),xi.flatten()])) # And this.

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi.reshape(xi.shape), alpha=0.5)

ax1.plot(y,x, "o")
ax1.set_xlim(0, 740)
ax1.set_ylim(515, 0)

im = plt.imread('statszone_football_pitch.jpg')
ax1.imshow(im, extent=[0, 740, 0, 515], aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

The result is this:

[image: pcolormesh over image]

I guess it's a kind of density plot for your scattered points.